# SAML2 request from Cordova is not working

Tags: cordova, saml-2.0

I'm working on integrating SAML2 SSO into an hybrid Cordova/Phonegap (Mendix) app. The redirect is working with this piece of code:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(mx.appUrl + "SSO/", "_blank", "location=yes,toolbar=yes");
```

However, the specific SSO login page is not displaying in the inAppBrowser, while it is working in the web application. I'm pretty sure I've set the whitelisting correctly:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

When looking at the network requests of the hybrid app however, I see that a 'SSO.saml2' request is there in red, contains the RelayState and SAMLRequest, but has 'provisional headers' (which should mean that the request is not actually fired). The elements just show a form with hidden fields...

[image: Screenshot of inspecting elements]

Does anybody have a clue why the request is not made?

Answer (score 1):

We found the issue; we don't have an SSL certificate for Test. In a normal webbrowser this gives a warning and the possibility to continue, while in the Cordova InAppBrowser you just get a white screen and blocked requests.